# How to sum two-dimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix, sketchup

let's say that I have two-dimensional arrays

```
array= [[10,12,15,17],[16,32,65,47],[45,48,41,23],[36,25,74,98],  [32,19,66,88],...]
```

I would like to do this in ruby

```
arr = [[10+45+32+..,12+48+19,15+41+66+..,17+23+88+..],   [16+36+..,32+25+..,65+74+..,47+98+..]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the sum of 2D Arrays in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013968/finding-the-sum-of-2d-arrays-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `partition` to separate and collect the even-indexed sub-arrays and odd-indexed sub-arrays. Then transpose each partition, followed by the sum of each newly formed sub-array.

```
array = [[10,12,15,17],[16,32,65,47],[45,48,41,23],[36,25,74,98],[32,19,66,88]]

array.partition.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }
               .map { |e| e.transpose.map(&:sum) }
#=> [[87, 79, 122, 128], [52, 57, 139, 145]]
```

*key methods:* `Enumerable#partition`,`Integer#even?` and `Array#transpose`. See [ruby-docs](http://ruby-doc.org) for more info. If you're using Ruby versions < 2.4.0, use `inject(:+)` instead of `sum`, as follows:

```
array.partition.with_index { |_,i| i.even? }
               .map { |e| e.transpose.map { |e| e.inject(:+) } }
#=> [[87, 79, 122, 128], [52, 57, 139, 145]]
```

Comment: undefined method ‘sum’ for [10, 45]:Array

Comment: @user7373737 `sum` works in Ruby 2.4.0. I've updated my answer, use this if you don't have Ruby 2.4.0 installed.

Comment: sagarpandya82 do you think this is posible: array[0..2]+array[3..5]+array[6..8]+array[.....]

Comment: @user7373737 yes I do. You should probably post it as a new question though:)